# Robot Framework Element Not Visible Exception

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I am receiving an ElementNotVisibleException though I am not sure why.  When I look at the screen capture in the logs, the element is clearly visible.  It is button with javascript controlling whether it is enabled or disabled.  Here's the disabled state:

```
<button id="continue" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg next pull-right btn-group-vertical" data-bind="enable: selectedRegistrationCandidates().length > 0" disabled="">Continue</button>
```

Here's the enabled state:

```
<button id="continue" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg next pull-right btn-group-vertical" data-bind="enable: selectedRegistrationCandidates().length > 0">Continue</button>
```

I am certain the element is enabled before I attempt the click but I get an ElementNotVisibleException when I try this:

```
Select Individual
   Click Element  ${lnkFirstPerson}
   Wait Until Page Does Not Contain   NOBODY SELECTED
   Wait Until Element Is Enabled    ${btnContinue}
   Click Element  ${btnContinue}
   Wait Until Page Contains    Return to Step 1
```

Can anyone explain why and a possible solution?

Comment: Just for curiosity - what happens if you put `Sleep | 2s` at the beginning, and end of `Click Element | id=continue` keyword? Also you should have a `Wait Until Element Is Visible | id=continue`

Comment: Also, could we see more of your Robot File?

Comment: could you share the code with us you have written so that we could understand better?

Comment: I just edited the the question so it contains more of the Keyword.  Everything passes until Click Element  ${btnContinue}

Comment: Also, @Goralight, I did try an explicit wait and still get the exception.  If I use Wait Until Element Is Visible, that fails.

Comment: Have you tried the Xpath of the element? what happens then?

Comment: @Goralight, yes xpath=//*[@id="continue"] --fails too.

Comment: Is the element inside a frame? Is there more than one element with the same locator?

Comment: @BryanOakley, in the source, there are actually two button's with an id="continue".  No to iframe.

Comment: @pgtips try `xpath=//*[@id="continue"][n]` to select the button you want. `n` being the order of which the buttons appear in the source

Comment: Ok, if there are two buttons with the same id, there's a good chance that the one you visually see isn't the one that selenium is picking. You need to use a locator that you know is guaranteed to pick the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities here.

1) **Switch to Frame where submit button is present:**

The Submit button is possibly in a different frame. If this is the case, first switch to frame and ten click the element.

Select Individual
       Click Element  ${lnkFirstPerson}

```
   Wait Until Page Does Not Contain   NOBODY SELECTED

   Select Frame  **Locator**   # i have added Select Frame Keyword here

   Wait Until Element Is Enabled    ${btnContinue}

   Click Element  ${btnContinue}

   Wait Until Page Contains    Return to Step 1
```

For more details you can refer: https://github.com/robotframework/Selenium2Library/issues/201

However. as this is not a normal practice so chances this is less.

2) Use JavaScript to do the action

Try using the keyword below.

Select Individual

```
   Click Element  ${lnkFirstPerson}

   Wait Until Page Does Not Contain   NOBODY SELECTED

   Wait Until Element Is Enabled    ${btnContinue}

   Execute JavaScript  $("#continue").click();

   # i have left Commented Click Element below to show  you changes i have         
   # made more clearly.I have added Javascript above.

   #Click Element  ${btnContinue}

   Wait Until Page Contains    Return to Step 1
```

Though this is not a recommended practice while writing scripts as it won't check if submit button actually appears on UI or not.But you can definitely can use it where you are sure element is present on UI.